# How to set dynamic height for rich:extendedDataTable rows?

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces, row

In my web application, I have `extendedDataTable` which shows records.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="tableID"
    ...>
    <rich:column width="110px">
        ...
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column width="110px">
        ...
    </rich:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

The issue is that
Some records have column value may be in multi-lines
*And the row height is not increased dynamically*
so some of data is not viewed
[image]

So Need to know how to set dynamic height for rich:extendedData rows?
Then the row height will be increase dynamicly when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the height for `.rf-edt-c`.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable styleClass="myTable" … />

.myTable .rf-edt-c {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This will indeed work, but when you start adapting JSF border width, all bets are off. A better solution is presented here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/170991?_sscc=t